# Bluetooth 4.0 app testing in Eclipse with Galaxy S4

Tags: android

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy s4 with Android version 4.2.2. Samsung has made a SDK for Bluetooth 4.0

http://developer.samsung.com/ble

and i have downloaded a sample (Proximity Profile (PXP) client) in this site, but i can't run the app. I think i have to download the

Samsung BLE SDK

file, i dont know where i have to include this file in Eclipse. The file includes the GATT class i need for the app.

How can i include this file in Eclipse ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you have to download the SDK.
Once done, open eclipse and import the PXP client project. Right click on the project in the "Package explorer" window and select properties.

Go to "Java Build Path" and select "Libraries" tab. Click on "Add External JARs..." then navigate to the downloaded BLE SDK package and load it.

Be sure to select and move the BLE package to the top on the "Order and Export" tab.